# Cast float to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with variables and values. The values column is in varchar(50).
How can I cast the values, so they appear as they are in the column "Want"?

| Variable | Want | cast([Value] as varchar(50)) | cast(CAST([Value] AS float) as varchar(50)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 77779999 | 7.778e+007 | 77779999 |
| b | -0.56 | -0.56 | -1 |
| c | 8.21 | 8.21 | 8 |

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

EDIT:

My original data is as follows and I want to transpose it in one column with type `varchar(50)`.

```
select 77779999 as var1, -0.56 as var2, 8.21 as var3
```

| var1 (INT) | var2 (float) | var3 (float) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 77779999 | -0.56 | 8.21 |

Comment: What datatype is your original data? Varchar(50)? Or Float? Its really not clear. And it seems like you are trying to use SQL Server to format your data, which is actually a job for your front end? Also are you sure you want a float? Floats should only be used in very specific circumstances - normally you want a decimal.

Comment: The problem is that you *can't* have different data types in the same column. You are better off *not* pivoting your data and doing the pivot in your presentation layer, where if can *present* the data in the format you want. In .Net that might be using the format style `0.##`.

Comment: so in the new column 77779999 would be 77779999.00?

Comment: What code do you have so far

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(f, v)  FROM (
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, Value) f , Value v
    FROM 
        (SELECT CAST(77779999 AS VARCHAR(50)) AS var1, CAST(-0.56 AS VARCHAR(50)) AS var2, CAST(8.21 AS VARCHAR(50)) AS var3) p
    UNPIVOT 
        (Value FOR ColumnName IN (var1, var2, var3)) AS unpvt
) s;
```

If the value is float, then it is cast to a FLOAT, otherwise not.

Another option is check for decimal point, this outputs varchar field.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN Value LIKE '%.%' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, Value))
    ELSE Value
END AS [wanted]
FROM 
    (SELECT CAST(77779999 AS VARCHAR(50)) AS var1, CAST(-0.56 AS VARCHAR(50)) AS var2, CAST(8.21 AS VARCHAR(50)) AS var3, CAST('aa444' as varchar(50)) AS var4) p
UNPIVOT 
    (Value FOR ColumnName IN (var1, var2, var3, var4)) AS unpvt
```